# How to drag and drop a mat-expansion-panel in to list of items inside a div in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to drag and drop the whole mat expansion panel in to a list of array, not a single item from panel. how to do this in Angular Material?

App Module

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
    import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
    import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
    import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        CarouselModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        DragDropModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatListModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

App component html

```html
    <div class="example-container">
      <h2>
        First Array Items
      </h2>
      <div
        cdkDropList
        #firstArrItem="cdkDropList"
        [cdkDropListData]="firstArr"
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[secondArrItem]"
        class="example-list"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of firstArr" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mat-wrapper">
      <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle
       cdkDropList
      #secondArrItem="cdkDropList"
      [cdkDropListData]="secondArr"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[firstArrItem]"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
      cdkDrag>
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title>
            This is the expansion title
          </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
         <mat-list>
             <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of secondArr" class="list-item" cdkDrag>
                {{item}}
             </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </div>
```

App component ts

```js
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import {
      CdkDragDrop,
      moveItemInArray,
      transferArrayItem,
    } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'test-app';
      firstArr = ['firstArr item 1', 'firstArr item 2', 'firstArr item 3', 'firstArr item 4'];
    
      secondArr = ['secondArr item 1', 'secondArr item 2', 'secondArr item 3', 'secondArr item 4'];
    
      drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
        if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
          moveItemInArray(
            event.container.data,
            event.previousIndex,
            event.currentIndex
          );
        } else {
          transferArrayItem(
            event.previousContainer.data,
            event.container.data,
            event.previousIndex,
            event.currentIndex
          );
        }
      }
    }
```

App component scss

```css
    .example-container {
      width: 400px;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .example-list {
      border: solid 1px #ccc;
      min-height: 60px;
      background: white;
      border-radius: 4px;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .example-box {
      padding: 20px 10px;
      border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      cursor: move;
      background: rgb(148, 145, 145);
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    .cdk-drag-preview {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
                  0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
                  0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    }
    
    .cdk-drag-placeholder {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .cdk-drag-animating {
      transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
    }
    
    .example-box:last-child {
      border: none;
    }
    
    .example-list.cdk-drop-list-dragging .example-box:not(.cdk-drag-placeholder) {
      transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
    }
    
    .list-item{
      background-color: #404040;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      color:  #fff;
      width: 400px;
      margin: 5px 0;
    }
    
    .mat-wrapper{
      width: 400px;
    }
    
    .mat-expansion-panel-header{
      background-color: lightgrey;
      color: green;
    }
    
    .mat-expansion-panel{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    }
```

Dragging the items from the array to dropping panel is working fine and similarly from panel to arrayList 1 is also working fine, but drag and drop the whole panel in to arrayList 1 is not happening

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reading the cdk drag drop docs for angular material? If you put the cdkDrag directive on the parent element of the expansion panel it should drag that entire element as desired.

Comment: You need to put `cdkDrag` in your element with `example-list` class. Tried the same in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g12lfv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-group-example.html)

Comment: I am putting the cdkDrag directive on the top also accroding to you on div with class mat wrapper then it does the same thing it actully drag the whole mat pannel and drop it where you want. In my case I want to drop it anywhere in arrayList 1